# OleDbConnection not found while using System.Data.OleDb namespace in code

Tags: c#, excel, xaml, uwp

i have read the other question with the same one without the `OldeDb` namespace in it. But I am still having a problem

I am creating a UWP app, and I want to upload a data from an Excel file to a DataGridView.

So this is my code

This is my reference code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb
```

then this is my code on uploading my excel file

```
String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fullDirectory + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + "2018" + "$]", con);
```

And this is my error code

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'OleDbCommand' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas why this is occurring? Thanks

Full Code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace App
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                this.Frame.GoBack();
            }
        }

        private async void BtnOpenAttendanceFileDialog_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
            picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.List;
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xls");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xlsx");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".dat");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv");


            Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                this.txtFileLocation.Text = file.Path;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        private void BtnLoadFile_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string fileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(txtFileLocation.Text.Trim());
            string fileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(txtFileLocation.Text.Trim());
            string fullDirectory = txtFileLocation.Text.Trim();

            String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fullDirectory + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + "2018" + "$]", con);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to doublecheck. You do have a `;` after `using System.Data.OleDb` in your own code?

Comment: @newboooooo Okay, `1.` have you added oledb as a reference to your project in your solution? `2.` Try pressing `ctrl + .` when you are standing on `new OleDbConnection(constr);` Does it say anything?  `3.` Try removing the using clause and do step `2` again.

Comment: Here it says https://imgur.com/a/mjyKZAU @Joel

Comment: @Joel I did the third step again, I also redid the whole project but still the same

Comment: You are missing an import. See step 1.

Comment: Ill try out that real quick @Joel

Comment: @Joel problem still exists

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. This is either a syntactical error or an import error.  Its working for me https://imgur.com/a/yzUKzcR

Comment: @Joel, I don't have any idea actually too because this is the third time I made the project & and the problem still occurs. I the new one actually still does have the same exact problem like the last two. Do you think I missed some stuff? Or I forgot to download some extensions of some sort?

Comment: Please check if you have these in your project https://imgur.com/a/mVRyyd0

Comment: @Joel I'll try to update my visual studio just in case. Thanks. Ill get to you back

Comment: @Joel tried the OleDb command on a ConsoleApp, it does work but I have no Idea why does it doesn't work on an UWP app

Comment: Here's the reference you need: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185500.aspx

Comment: @Joel stil doesn't work sadly. I'll still keep looking just in case

Comment: What version of c# are u running. Please look here for requirements: https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Data#uwp . make sure u are importing `System.Data.Common`

Comment: Change `public sealed partial class MainPage: Page` to `public static class MainPage : Page`

Comment: @Joel i changed `public sealed partial class MainPage: Page` to `public sealed partial class MainPage: Page` and the one you have suggested. I think I am using the latest one. It says on my side my target is Universal Windows. Target is Win10 Ver1809 and minimum is Win10 Ver1803

Comment: Please see my answer. Do you really need a UWP app? Otherwise i would highly suggest that you change your project type. Because oleDb is not supported in a UWP application.

Comment: @Joel, yes sadly. That's what they want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging (which can be found in the comments) I've found that you can only use a small subset of .NET in a UWP application.

Creating a simple console-application will verify that there isn't a problem with your Visual Studio installation. [Eg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXREa.jpg):

```
namespace App
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         using(var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection{connString = "..info.."})
        {
             conn.Open();
             Console.WriteLine("DS:{0} DB: {1}",conn.DataSource,conn.Database);   
        }
    }
}
```

Its simply that UWP does not support `OleDbConnection`. 
Please see more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185501.aspx) on what you can use. Also, have a look at: [API's of UWP](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Data#uwp) to verify that you are on the correct version.

Also, this error can be caused by having multiple reference variants to `System.Data` for everyone else stumbling across this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try another way to fix this out