# VB.NET 2019 OLE Data Connection Through Code

Tags: vb.net, ole

I am experiencing a peculiar problem in VB.NET 2019. While trying to connect to an OLE database via the following code, none of the references are working:

`Dim LocalDatabaseCon As New OleDbConnection
    Dim Command As OleDbCommand`

The Imports statement also does not work. For example the statement `Imports System.Data.OLEDB` does not work. 
I have used this code numerous times in VB,NET 2010 and 2017.

An internet search prompted me to add references from the project properties but the in the window, there are no references to data objects.
I also cannot find any data references in the Object Browser.
Khalid.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using e.g. .NET Core 3.1?

Comment: The Target Framework shows 4.7.2

Comment: I have just created a .NET 4.7.2 VB.NET app using VS 2019 and I can add Imports System.Data.OLEDB and use the namespace.  It works out of the box i.e. no need to add references.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194723/oledbconnection-not-found-while-using-system-data-oledb-namespace-in-code

Comment: What type of project?

Comment: It is a Windows Forms project. Today, VS-2019 also received an update. To be on the safe side, I restarted the computer after the update but the errors persist.

Comment: Ok, I was able to solve the issue by going to the Solution Explorer>References>and switching on System.Data. Thank you everyone for your efforts.